# checkbox array not updating correct records in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

i have a form that contains a table which is dynamically created from an mysql query.

Each row contains a persons name and a checkbox. what i am trying to do is have the persons record updated with a 1 if the checkbox is checked or 0 if it is unchecked.

The problem is that when i use the below code, the right number of records are updated but not for the right person.
here is the relevant form code:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '
        <tr>
            <td align="left">'. ucfirst($row['CustNumber']) .'</td>
            <td align="left">'. ucfirst($row['Firstname']) .' '. ucfirst($row['Surname']) .'</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="cid[]"  value="'. $row['CustNumber'] .'">
                <input type="hidden" name="cbox[]"  value="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]"  value="1">
            </td>   
        </tr>';
}
```

and here is a simplified processing page:

```
    foreach ($_POST['cid'] as $key=>$custid) {
    $check = $_POST['cbox'][$key];
        if ($check == "1") {
            $update ="UPDATE customer SET Active = '1' where CustID = '$custid'";
            $updatequery = mysqli_query($con,$update);
        } 
        else {
            $update ="UPDATE customer SET Active = '0' where CustID = '$custid'";
            $updatequery = mysqli_query($con,$update);
        }
    }
```

can some tell me where i am going wrong? feel like I'm close but cant put it all together.

UPDATE:
changing :

```
<td align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="cid[]"  value="'. $row['CustNumber'] .'">
            <input type="hidden" name="cbox[]"  value="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]"  value="1">
        </td>
```

to:

```
<td align="center">
         <input type="hidden" name="cid['. $row['CustID'] .']"  value="'. $row['CustID'] .'">
         <input type="checkbox" name="cbox['. $row['CustID'] .']"  value="1"'>
        </td>
```

has solved the issue, as per showdev's comment.Thanks

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` you hopefully see what your doing wrong by looking at the data you have

Comment: I have edited the code on the processing page to to show a query, although i know there is no problem with that. The problem i have is with the information coming from the form. When i echo the info it shows the wrong customer numbers with the checked selection.

Comment: It's related to mismatched input "keys". Set them explicitly, as in the "duplicate" post. Then, not only will your inputs stay coordinated, you won't need to include hidden inputs to account for unchecked (hence unposted) checkboxes.